# Test Flight. Add internal testers

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

According to test flight video tutorial after I add internal tester to my build, status should be "Invited" and he should receive email with invitation to test. In my case I have status "Added" and I didn't receive any email from itunes connect. What I am doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you set "TestFlight Beta Testing" to "on" in Builds tab ?

Comment: @Rafouille, yes it is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be normal, you have to wait for apple to send the invitations. See here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html

> You can see the status of each tester in the Internal Testers and External Testers panes. When testers are added as TestFlight beta testers, their status becomes Added. When invitations are sent to the testers, their status changes to Invited. As your testers accept their invitations, their status changes to Accepted. When they download the app, their status changes to Testing, and the Latest Build column shows the latest build they have installed.

Comment: Yes you are rigth, it took about 30 min to get invitation email.